# Select all active stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Is there a way to select all active stored procedures in my database?  I recently dropped a couple thousand and want to make sure I didn't miss any. It will be easier for me to pinpoint them if I can see what is active.

Comment: no - the database engine does not track "active" procedures. You might, in fact, have procedures that are critical but used rarely - like at the end of a calendar or fiscal year. Are those "active"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jonlabelle.com/snippets/view/sql/get-stored-procedure-statistics

Get SQL Server stored procedure statistics, including name, schema, last execution time, create and modify date, and execution count since last reboot.

```
select db_name(proc_stats.database_id) as dbname,
    sc.name as [schema],
    obj.name,
    proc_stats.last_execution_time,
    obj.modify_date,
    obj.create_date,
    proc_stats.execution_count
from sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats as proc_stats
inner join sys.objects as obj
    on obj.object_id = proc_stats.object_id
inner join sys.schemas as sc
    on obj.schema_id = sc.schema_id
where obj.type = 'P'
order by dbname,
    sc.name,
    obj.name;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-procedure-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Returns aggregate performance statistics for cached stored procedures.

```
SELECT d.object_id, d.database_id, OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) 'proc name',   
    d.cached_time, d.last_execution_time, d.total_elapsed_time,  
    d.total_elapsed_time/d.execution_count AS [avg_elapsed_time],  
    d.last_elapsed_time, d.execution_count  
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS d  
ORDER BY [total_worker_time] DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

This script returns all the proceudres (not active or inactive):

```
 SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) SP_Name
              ,OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) SP_Definition
        FROM   sys.procedures
```

an additional question: What version are you working on?

Comment: this just shows all procedures whether active or not?  i'm on sql server 2016

Comment: There is no such thing as an active stored procedure in SQL Server, it either exists or it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

You can combine sys.procedures with syscomments to find usage in your other procedures. This will only work if your database procedures are not encrypted.

```
select allproc.name from sys.procedures allproc
outer apply (
    select object_name(p.object_id) used_in_procname from syscomments c
        join sys.procedures p on p.object_id = c.id
        and p.object_id != allproc.object_id
     where c.text like concat('%',allproc.name,'%')
) usages where used_in_procname is null
```